# $query->set orderby type not working as expected

Tags: wordpress, hook

I'm trying to prioritise search results by post type, using `pre_get_posts` hook - `track` post type results `administration` post type results.
I'm not sure if it can be done with `$query->set( 'orderby', 'type' )`. Using the same arguments in WP_Query will work, but I want to avoid that.

This is the full function:

```
function tcb_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
       return;

    if ( is_search() ) {
       $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'track', 'administration' )  );
       $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 15 );
       $query->set( 'orderby', 'type' );
       // orderby 'post_type' did not work as well
   }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'tcb_pre_get_posts', 1 );
```

Altough `track` is written before `administration` in the `post_type` array, in the results I see `administration` before `track`.

Comment: check this link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91890/add-multiple-orderby-with-pre-get-posts

Comment: What is the problem with your code exactly? It looks like it is doing what you want? can you describe what you are expecting?

Comment: Und3rTow, Thank you for this comment. Just edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are looking to change the `order` which your custom post types are being displayed, for that you can just specify either `ASC` or `DESC` using `$query->set('order','ASC');`:

```
function tcb_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
       return;

    if ( is_search() ) {
       $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'track', 'administration' )  );
       $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 15 );
       $query->set( 'orderby', 'type' );
       $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' ); // or DESC
   }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'tcb_pre_get_posts', 1 );
```